# Spring Cloud Zuul CircuitBreaker All Routes via TurbineStream Not Turbine-AMQP

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, turbine

I'm using spring boot 1.3.1 and spring cloudl Brixtom.M4, While using springboot 1.3.1 i found that Turbine-AMQP project is no longer available instead we have now Spring Turbine Stream project.
I what to user SpringTurbine with rabbitmq or kafka and want to monitor hystrix stream of all routes registered in Zuul, I'm able to see the hystrix.stream for the zuul and also able to see that in hystrix dashboard, but not sure how to use the spring turbine stream. 
On the net i found the code and documentation for using Turbine AMQP.

I have zuul server running ad http://localhost:9003/ with depedencies

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and main.java as

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class EdgeServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EdgeServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I also have springTurbinestream project as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-turbine-stream</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-actuator

and main class for TurbineStream as

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTurbineStream
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class WiziqTurbineApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WiziqTurbineApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I run the application and go to http://localhost:9003/hystrix.stream i see the stream but if i go to http://localhost:9003/turbine.stream it going on error.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the reason for downvoting :(

Comment: I did not downvote, but I do not see a programming question.  I might be wrong, but I also think it is a bit broad.

Comment: ok fair enough but still if you know the answer please post that

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about other that Spring Boot.  What exactly you do not understand about the way it works?  Reformat the question to be fitting for this site, ie some kind of code.  If you cannot, then just delete the question and research it yourself then come back if there are any specific programming questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client app (on port 9003) is not supposed to have a `/turbine.stream`. It is supposed to send messages with hystrix metrics to rabbit (for instance). To make it do that you need to add `spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream` and `spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit` (just like you did on the server for the `*-turbine-*` dependencies).

Comment: out of curiosity what is the difference between spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp and spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit

Comment: spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-stream is not avaliable did you mean spring-cloud-starter-turbine-stream

Comment: if i use spring-cloud-starter-turbine-stream then on registering with eureka i see two instances one UP and on Starting. I guess this is happening because of RxNetty server. and that instance always remain in starting state, same happen with Turbine-stream project.

Comment: Updated. Sorry about the typo in the dependency name (there's no starter for hystrix stream, just the library).

Comment: You do not need (and should never have) turbine in a client app in any form (stream, amqp, vanilla, whatever).

Comment: "what is the difference between spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp and spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit ". One is Spring Cloud Bus for rabbit and the other is Spring Cloud Stream. Different functionality (one builds on top of the other in fact).

Comment: mvn could not find spring-cloud-hystrix-stream and when i use spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream after some time zuul re-register it self with eureka with starting state. I'm using Eureka first to find config server

Comment: Sorry, I got the jar name wrong again. Should be fixed now. If you have a question about eureka registration I suggest you ask that separately.

Comment: I have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851294/using-hystrix-stream-in-zuul-with-eureka-first-to-find-config-server