# Using Hystrix Stream in Zuul with Eureka First to find Config server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I'm using spring cloud Brixton.M4 with spring boot 1.3.1

I have zuul server with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and i'm using Eureka first to find Config-Server so bootstrap looks like

```
spring:
 profiles: dev 
 cloud:
   config:
     fail-fast: true
     discovery:
       enabled: true
       serviceId: config-server
```

zuul is registring two time first with **UP** state then with **STARTING**

```
2016-01-18 14:47:27.209  INFO 2808 --- [           main] c.w.i.edgeserver.EdgeServerApplication   : Started EdgeServerApplication in 21.651 seconds (JVM running for 22.232)
2016-01-18 14:47:56.231  INFO 2808 --- [ool-20-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_EDGE-SERVER/192.168.17.178:edge-server:8003 - Re-registering apps/EDGE-SERVER
2016-01-18 14:47:56.270  INFO 2808 --- [ool-20-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_EDGE-SERVER/192.168.17.178:edge-server:8003: registering service...
2016-01-18 14:47:56.281  INFO 2808 --- [ool-20-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_EDGE-SERVER/192.168.17.178:edge-server:8003 - registration status: 204
2016-01-18 14:48:06.230  INFO 2808 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_EDGE-SERVER/192.168.17.178:edge-server:8003: registering service...
2016-01-18 14:48:06.238  INFO 2808 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_EDGE-SERVER/192.168.17.178:edge-server:8003 - registration status: 204
```

If I remove dependency on config-server by setting

```
spring:
 profiles: dev 
 cloud:
   config:
     fail-fast: false
     discovery:
       enabled: false
       serviceId: config-server
```

everything runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal I think (the bootstrap phase has to register to get the configserver location, and then unregister to let the main application register again). You will probably find that it settles back to UP after the application has started up fully.

Comment: but problem is that it never go to UP state, and strange thing is that every thing runs fine. Routes, Loadbalancing, Hystrix Stream, Rabbit Steam, and the Management.

Comment: Well it works for me. Try with snapshots? Post a sample project?

Comment: ok i'll try that and post the sample project, Out of curiosity Is Brixton will be release this month?? :)

Comment: hi i'm still having the issue. i used the snapshot build, here is git url https://github.com/dinkarthakur/spring-cloud-sample . its eureka first approach. so DiscoveryServer boot first then ConfigServer and lastly doss-edge-server. First it shows EDGE-SERVICE in UP state in eureka and after some time appx 90 sec it goes to  STARTING state and stuck forever. All functionalities are working fine though. Can you please have look :(

Comment: I ran your sample and the edge service is showing STATUS=UP after 3 minutes. So I guess it still works for me. How are you starting the processes?

Comment: using sts to run the application java version "1.8.0_66". even i tried with mvn package and then running the fat jar using java - jar

Comment: Still working for me. Maybe there's something else in your environment? Another eureka client trying to claim that port?

Comment: still not able to figure out the issue but when i tried it on fresh machine it works.  On my older machine i was running many other services like RabitMq, redis, mongo and es.  so i guess there was some conflict. But point is when I remove spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream depedency all work fine .